# somgthing about Custom View with Xib

Tags: ios, objective-c

I create a custom view "HelpNaviView",and add a xib file to it.Everything is ok,but the display size is wrong.
Here is my code:

```
- (instancetype) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame WithTitle:(NSString*)title AndSuperVC:(UIViewController*)superVC{
    NSArray*array=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"HelpNaviView" owner:nil options:nil];
    self=array[0];
    NSLog(@"array%@",array);
    self.frame=Frame(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, 64);
    self.titleLabel.text=title;
    self.superVC=superVC;
    return self;
}
```

...

```
HelpNaviView*navi=[[HelpNaviView alloc]initWithFrame:ZeroRect WithTitle:@"历史反馈" AndSuperVC:self];
NSLog(@"navi%@",navi);
[self.view addSubview:navi];
```

And printInfo:

```
array(
    "<HelpNaviView: 0x7feb830ce180; frame = (0 0; 375 64); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7feb830ec980>>"
)
2015-10-13 19:34:12.275 RLCementEBusiness[32071:1778329] navi<HelpNaviView: 0x7feb830ce180; frame = (0 0; 375 64); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7feb830ec980>>
```

But the display image is:
[Simulator Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXazU.jpg)

Comment: what's wrong? you are setting frame to (0,0,screen_width,64) in initWithFrame method

Comment: GUESS, grey area should fill whole screen width. - could it be that the label covers your view? what is self and what other subviews are involved

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati yes,you can look at my simulator image,the display size is (150.0,131.0),not (375,64)

Comment: @Daij-Djan self is a custom view "HelpNaviView",all subviews is normal displsyed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems you are using a constant for width: SCREEN_WIDTH.
It should be:

```
self.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, superVC.view.frame.width, 64)
```

Also it is important to init this custom view from viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear, not viewDidLoad.

Comment: here from my SCREEN_WIDTH:"#define SCREEN_WIDTH ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width)" is it any wrong?

Comment: do not use define tags in iOS. They are not type safe, so it should be avoided as plague.

Comment: I take your step ,then something unbelievable changes.The width is normal,but the height is still wrong.Could you tell me more detail reason?And how about the height?

Comment: i am not sure when does the values being created when you use define. But the problem was that, when your defined value got initialized, it took the wrong value.
Now your height than. What are you experiencing? Too small?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line.

```
self.frame=Frame(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 64);
```

//don't call bellow lines in viewDidLoad method. Because before creating the view you can't set frame.

```
HelpNaviView*navi=[[HelpNaviView alloc]initWithFrame:ZeroRect WithTitle:@"历史反馈" AndSuperVC:self];
NSLog(@"navi%@",navi);
[self.view addSubview:navi];
```

it is Better to avoid this 
      self.frame=Frame(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 64);
Instead the above line, you can set frame in the nib file

Comment: my "SCREEN_WIDTH" from "#define SCREEN_WIDTH ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width)", is here any difference?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using autolayout, you should provide your own constraints for subview, because default constraints are different from what you expected

Add constraints manually

```
navi.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self addSubview: navi];

NSDictionary *views = @{@"navi": navi};

[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                      constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[navi]|"
                      options:0
                      metrics:nil
                      views:views]];

[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                      constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[navi]"
                      options:0
                      metrics:nil
                      views:views]];

[navi addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:navi
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                    toItem:nil
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                multiplier:1.0 
constant:64]];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I set the "translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO",and make subview constraints in xib,but still wrong displayed size.

Comment: did you add constraints inside HelpNaviView? you should set up constraints between instance of HelpNaviView and it's superview. Did you try the following code?